# Toggle paragraphs in different divs when you click on a specific div

Tags: jquery

I have a background image with multiple divs on top acting as "labels" for parts of the image. I only want the heading/title of the div to show and then when you click on the div, the paragraph (the description) shows (kind of like a 'read more'). Each div has it's own id and each paragraph I want to show has it's own id. I am new to using jQuery and cannot figure out how to:

1. Group my jQuery together so it's not so repetitive
2. Close the open paragraph when you click on another "label" to view more (so if i clicked on the first label to read the description and then click on the second to read the second description, the first one should close).
3. Reposition the div when the paragraph is revealed so it's correctly placed on the specific part of the image (right now I have it happening with .animate, but I can't figure out how to make it go back to it's normal position when the paragraph closes). Not sure if that's right.
4. make the font awesome "down caret face up" when the paragraph is visible, and back down when it is not visible.

here it is on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dmo1111/8n1bLb52/#&togetherjs=cB0QuczANm

css

```
[mobile] {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 10px 50px 10px;
    [info~="mobile"] {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 10;
            top: -10px;
        #show1,
                #show2,
                #show3,
                #show4,
                #show5,
                #show6,
                #show7 {
                    display: none;
                    padding-bottom: 15px;
                }
        }
}
```

html

```
<div mobile>
  <div info="mobile" id="mobile1">
    <h3 class="great-primer">Title 1 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></h3>
    <p class="long-primer" id="show1">Paragprah description for first label.</p>
  </div>
  <div info="mobile" id="mobile2">
    <h3 class="great-primer">Title 2 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></h3>
    <p class="long-primer" id="show2">Paragprah description for second label.</p>
  </div>
  <div info="mobile" id="mobile3">
    <h3 class="great-primer">Title 3 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></h3>
    <p class="long-primer" id="show3">Paragprah description for third label.</p>
  </div>
  <div info="mobile" id="mobile4">
    <h3 class="great-primer">Title 4 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></h3>
    <p class="long-primer" id="show4">Paragprah description for fourth label.</p>
  </div>
  <div info="mobile" id="mobile5">
    <h3 class="great-primer">Title 5 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></h3>
    <p class="long-primer" id="show5">Paragraph description for fifth label.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$("#mobile1").click(function() {
  $("#show1").toggle(1000);
  $(this).animate({
    top: '10px'
  });
});
$("#mobile2").click(function() {
  $("#show2").toggle(1000);
  $(this).animate({
    top: '20px'
  });
});
$("#mobile3").click(function() {
  $("#show3").toggle(1000);
  $(this).animate({
    top: '50px'
  });
});
$("#mobile4").click(function() {
  $("#show4").toggle(1000);
  $(this).animate({
    top: '60px'
  });
});
$("#mobile5").click(function() {
  $("#show5").toggle(1000);
  $(this).animate({
    top: '80px'
  });
});
```

Sorry if this looks like a big mess/a lot at once! I've searched a bunch of forums all morning to help me with this and have had no luck. I was hoping I could figure it out on my own, but I also don't know nearly enough about jQuery to ensure that it's the "simplest" If anyone could help me I would be so grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified version of your code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mobile1, #mobile2, #mobile3, #mobile4, #mobile5").click(function() {
       $(this).find('.long-primer').toggle(1000);
       var divTop = $(this).position().top;
       $(this).animate({
       top: divTop+'10px'
     });
   }); 
});
</script>
```

---

**Better option:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Example</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Title 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Paragprah description for first label.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Title 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Paragprah description for second label.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Title 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Paragprah description for third label.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">Title 4</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Paragprah description for fourth label.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">Title 5</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Paragprah description for fifth label.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much I really appreciate you taking the time to help! however, it's only working for two of the divs and the animation goes off the page (it's not being contained in the  container div). The animation also doesn't go back to it's normal state. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I copied it exactly how you have it.

Comment: Yes I did, it wasn't working either :(. I made a work around and positioned the divs so that they didn't need to reposition upon toggling the paragraph. Thank you so much though because the simplified version of my code you provided above solved most of my problems!